# Replace a specific tag with another tag

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, css-selectors, nokogiri

So I have this html (located in some XML file)

```
<span style=" font-style: italic;">Nature, </span>
```

My **desired** result is to use Ruby, Nokogiri or css-selectors to replace the  tag with

```
<i>Nature, </i>
```

I have tried the following:

So I read the Xml and get the content

```
page_references = doc.xpath("/wcm:root/wcm:element[@name='Citations']").inner_text
```

Here I try to look for the tag with in the content and replace it

```
page_data.push (page_references.to_s.gsub!(/<span style=" font-style: italic;">/,'<i>'))
```

This does not replace the closing tags.

Has any one got any suggestions on how I can achieve my **desired** result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require "nokogiri"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment('<span style=" font-style: italic;">Nature, </span>')

doc.css('span[style=" font-style: italic;"]')
.each{|span| span.replace("<i>#{span.content}</i>")}

doc.to_s # => "<i>Nature, </i>"
```

Comment: Thanks sawa very elegant

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse <<-eot
<span style=" font-style: italic;">Nature, </span>
eot

node = doc.at_css('span[style=" font-style: italic;"]')
node.replace("<i> #{node.text} </i>")

puts doc
```

**Output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org
   /TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
   <body><i> Nature,  </i></body>
</html>
```

Comment: @devArled it is [`node.text`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-text)...